# Wordpress query_posts from GET submission

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying - and failing miserably - to construct a new `query_posts` query using the values from a form submitted using Wordpress' `wp_dropdown_categories`.

Here's the form:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url')/filter.php" method="GET">
  <?php wp_dropdown_categories('child_of=1&name=colour'); ?>
  <?php wp_dropdown_categories('child_of=2&name=type'); ?>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
</form>
```

Which renders the following HTML (simplified a little to save space)

```
<form action="http://localhost:8888/project/wp-content/themes/project/filter.php" method="GET">
  <select name='colour' id='colour' class='postform' >
    <option value="3">Red</option>
    <option value="4">Blue</option>
    <option value="5">Blue</option>
  </select>
  <select name='type' id='colour' class='postform' >
    <option value="6">Small</option>
    <option value="7">Medium</option>
    <option value="8">Large</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
</form>
```

And here's the `filter.php` file contents

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'category__in' => array(HELP HERE);
  query_posts( $args );

  // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      echo '<li>';the_title();
      echo '</li>';
    endwhile;

  // Reset Query
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

The most important factor here is that this needs to be flexible; in other words if only one of the selects is used, the query should still work.

I think I'm most of the way there, it's just construction the array for the `category__in => array()` from the values of any of the selected options that's doing my head in.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: the HTML looks broken. Please post valid code here. And which parts of http://php.net/forms do not allow you to achieve your goals?

Comment: Updated the HTML - sorry about that. Thanks for the link, that looks promising, but I need to build an array of any and all $_GET['id'] which I don't know how to do.

Comment: Shouldn't there be two select tags?

Comment: Yes - as I said above the HTML, I've simplified it to save space.

Comment: Well I guess in your case it's important to have it work with both selects so I think you should not cut it. (I also asked mods to move this to a more fitting site, just in case that happens, don't wonder).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for now.

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'category__in' => array($_GET['colour'], $_GET['type'])
  );
  query_posts( $args );

// The Loop
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';the_title();
    echo '</li>';
  endwhile;

// Reset Query
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Also, it's better to use `category__and' instead of 'category__in' in this case.